(R3F/React-three-fiber/Ecctrl) gltfpack with gltfjsx - my packed .glb model is not loading
code sandbox link here
I'm using ecctrl and react-three-fiber.
My character model isn't loading and I don't know how to debug it? Any ideas?
I used something like `gltfpack -i ./inputfile.glb -o ./Character-packed.glb -c
Maybe I need to experiment with different options but the whole point is to compress the animated character file.
Here's the commands I'm using:
npx gltfpack@latest -i ./input.glb -o ./Character-packed.glb -c
npx gltfjsx@6.4.1 ./Character-packed-glb -M
which gives this output:
/*
Auto-generated by: https://github.com/pmndrs/gltfjsx
Command: npx gltfjsx@6.5.0 ./public/characters/Animated/Character-packed.glb 
*/

import React from 'react'
import { useGraph } from '@react-three/fiber'
import { useGLTF, useAnimations } from '@react-three/drei'
import { SkeletonUtils } from 'three-stdlib'

export function Model(props) {
  const group = React.useRef()
  const { scene, animations } = useGLTF('/Character-packed.glb')
  const clone = React.useMemo(() => SkeletonUtils.clone(scene), [scene])
  const { nodes, materials } = useGraph(clone)
  const { actions } = useAnimations(animations, group)
  console.log('actions', actions)
  return (
    <group ref={group} {...props} dispose={null}>
      <group name="Scene">
        <group name="Armature" rotation={[Math.PI / 2, 0, 0]} scale={0.001}>
          <primitive object={nodes.mixamorigHips} />
          <group name="Dress">
            <group position={[-0.098, 0, -0.021]} scale={0}>
              <skinnedMesh name="mesh_0" geometry={nodes.mesh_0.geometry} material={materials['Material.045']} skeleton={nodes.mesh_0.skeleton} />
              <skinnedMesh name="mesh_0_1" geometry={nodes.mesh_0_1.geometry} material={materials['Material.046']} skeleton={nodes.mesh_0_1.skeleton} />
              <skinnedMesh name="mesh_0_2" geometry={nodes.mesh_0_2.geometry} material={materials['Material.048']} skeleton={nodes.mesh_0_2.skeleton} />
              <skinnedMesh name="mesh_0_3" geometry={nodes.mesh_0_3.geometry} material={materials['Material.001']} skeleton={nodes.mesh_0_3.skeleton} />
            </group>
          </group>
          <group name="Glasses">
            <skinnedMesh name="mesh_1" geometry={nodes.mesh_1.geometry} material={materials['Material.052']} skeleton={nodes.mesh_1.skeleton} position={[-0.098, 0, -0.021]} scale={0} />
          </group>
          <group name="Gloves">
            <skinnedMesh name="mesh_2" geometry={nodes.mesh_2.geometry} material={materials['Material.047']} skeleton={nodes.mesh_2.skeleton} position={[-0.098, 0, -0.021]} scale={0} />
          </group>
          <group name="Hair009">
            <skinnedMesh name="mesh_3" geometry={nodes.mesh_3.geometry} material={materials['Material.033']} skeleton={nodes.mesh_3.skeleton} position={[-0.098, 0, -0.021]} scale={0} />
          </group>
          <group name="Headphone">
            <group position={[-0.098, 0, -0.021]} scale={0}>
              <skinnedMesh name="mesh_4" geometry={nodes.mesh_4.geometry} material={materials['Material.055']} skeleton={nodes.mesh_4.skeleton} />
              <skinnedMesh name="mesh_4_1" geometry={nodes.mesh_4_1.geometry} material={materials['Material.056']} skeleton={nodes.mesh_4_1.skeleton} />
              <skinnedMesh name="mesh_4_2" geometry={nodes.mesh_4_2.geometry} material={materials['Material.058']} skeleton={nodes.mesh_4_2.skeleton} />
              <skinnedMesh name="mesh_4_3" geometry={nodes.mesh_4_3.geometry} material={materials['Material.059']} skeleton={nodes.mesh_4_3.skeleton} />
              <skinnedMesh name="mesh_4_4" geometry={nodes.mesh_4_4.geometry} material={materials['Material.060']} skeleton={nodes.mesh_4_4.skeleton} />
            </group>
          </group>
          <group name="Skin011">
            <skinnedMesh name="mesh_5" geometry={nodes.mesh_5.geometry} material={materials['Material.002']} skeleton={nodes.mesh_5.skeleton} position={[-0.098, 0, -0.021]} scale={0} />
          </group>
        </group>
      </group>
    </group>
  )
}

useGLTF.preload('/Character-packed.glb')

Then in App.jsx we import the above component:
import { Canvas } from '@react-three/fiber'
import { Physics } from '@react-three/rapier'
import { Environment, KeyboardControls } from '@react-three/drei'
import { Perf } from 'r3f-perf'
import { Suspense } from 'react'
import Ecctrl, { EcctrlAnimation } from 'ecctrl'

import Lights from './Lights'
import Map from './Map'
import { Model as CharacterModel } from './Character-packed'

export default function App() {
  /**
   * Keyboard control preset
   */
  const keyboardMap = [
    { name: 'forward', keys: ['ArrowUp', 'KeyW'] },
    { name: 'backward', keys: ['ArrowDown', 'KeyS'] },
    { name: 'leftward', keys: ['ArrowLeft', 'KeyA'] },
    { name: 'rightward', keys: ['ArrowRight', 'KeyD'] },
    { name: 'jump', keys: ['Space'] },
    { name: 'run', keys: ['Shift'] },
    { name: 'action1', keys: ['1'] },
    { name: 'action2', keys: ['2'] },
    { name: 'action3', keys: ['3'] },
    { name: 'action4', keys: ['KeyF'] }
  ]

  /**
   * Character url preset
   */
  const characterURL = './Character-packed.glb'
//...
return (
    <Canvas
      shadows
      onPointerDown={(e) => {
        e.target.requestPointerLock()
      }}>
      <Perf position="top-left" />
      <Environment background files="/night.hdr" />
      <Lights />
      <Suspense fallback={null}>
        <Physics timeStep="vary">
          <KeyboardControls map={keyboardMap}>
            <Ecctrl debug animated>
              <CharacterModel />
              {/* {<EcctrlAnimation characterURL={characterURL} animationSet={animationSet}>
                <CharacterModel />
              </EcctrlAnimation>} */}
            </Ecctrl>
          </KeyboardControls>
          <Map />
        </Physics>
      </Suspense>
    </Canvas>
  )
}

I found that gltfjsx@6.5.0 doesn't see to work to transform models anymore so I used 6.4.1 instead which works.
I'm not sure how to use gltfpack such that I can import the model into r3f with gltfjsx and render it out without it being invisible.
I did some debugging and it seems like it find animations but can't clips.forEach because clips becomes missing at some point.
It is something around the clone and passing empty animations into useAnimations.
Thanks

@Rabbid76 thank you for helping me improve my question, I've added to relevant code and commands I used.

There's a lot going on in this scene... Have you noticed that it's not like the model doesn't render, it just disappears after a few seconds? Sometimes I saw it all the time, sometimes for just a few seconds, sometimes changes position on the Y axis, strange... Most likely there will be a conflict somewhere between animations/physics etc. Maybe try to simplify the scene as much as possible and add components step by step.

I need help with understanding how to use gltfpack and gltfjsx together to render a compressed animated model in r3f.

const { scene, animations } = useGLTF('/characters/Animated/Character-packed.glb')

Update the path of model
